# Creating a custom OrderByDescending() for an IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, iqueryable

Here are some examples of the values I'd like to sort from high to low.

```
8,929 viewers
18,213 viewers
2,223 viewers
41,231 viewers
```

And here is an example of the query I'm using:

```
streams = streamRepository.FindAll()
                          .OrderByDescending(s => s.ViewCount)
                          .Take(4);
```

This isn't working correctly as I imagine it's taking the parameter as a string, not an int but that's not surprising.

How do you suggest I create this "ordering" using clean C# / Linq code?

Ideally, using the data examples above, the resulting ordered set would be:

```
41,231 viewers
18,213 viewers
8,929 viewers
2,223 viewers
```

Comment: What database are you querying?

Comment: @Gabe: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: If the values are numbers, you should store them as numbers in your database.

Comment: @svick: That's my *last* resort. Let's see if somebody smarter than my cook up some Linq wizardry.

Comment: How many rows do you have? If you have a lot, then this will be inefficient because the database will have to sort the whole table. It it's not a lot, you might as well do the sorting client-side to make the code easier to write.

Comment: Time to refactor your database schema into something more appropriate - this is the only sane way for a long-term solution.

Comment: @Gabe: No more than 4000 rows.

Comment: @svick: It seems there is not a clean and efficient way to do this the way I wanted to. I've bitten the bullet and refactored into a simple int column in my table and ordered the collection by that. It's working fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always the same, I'd give this a shot:

```
streams = streamRepository.FindAll()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(s => 
        int.Parse(s.ViewCount.Substring(0, s.ViewCount.IndexOf(' ') - 1))
    .Take(4);
```

Comment: Are you sure EF can translate `string.Split()` into SQL?

Comment: @svick: That's my concern as well.

Comment: @JustinNiessner, I was thinking you could do it using of `IndexOf()` and `Substring()`, but I'm too lazy to actually try it out.

Comment: @Justin: Are you saying that `string.Substring` doesn't translate into the T-SQL `SUBSTRING` function? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: @Gabe - I didn't think it did (even though it should) but apparently I'm wrong. Either that or it worked in LINQ to SQL and they removed it in Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the neatest solution. But maybe something like this:

```
streamRepository.FindAll()
        .OrderByDescending(t => t =>Convert.ToDouble(
                 t.ViewCount.Substring(0,t.ViewCount.IndexOf(' '))))
```

The sql generated. Do not get that horrible and it works in linqpad:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 0
DECLARE @p1 NChar(1) = ' '
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[SomeText]
FROM [Table1] AS [t0]
ORDER BY CONVERT(Float,SUBSTRING([t0].[SomeText], @p0 + 1, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN (DATALENGTH(@p1) / 2) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE CHARINDEX(@p1, [t0].[SomeText]) - 1
     END))) DESC
```

Because linq can translate `substring` and `indexof` to sql functions. But this is also really specific to the format. Like in the comment to your question I would also suggest you splitting the column into to column.

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using? I didn't think String.Substring had a translation in EF.

Comment: Maybe I miss read the question. It works in linq to sql. Not really sure about EF. Because he said that the query would return a IQuerable then is'nt he executing it against the database and the end result will be a sql statement?

Comment: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double ToDouble(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 0):

something like (more pseudo, didn't test for anything but should be close)...

```
streams = streamRepository.FindAll()
                          .Select(s=> new { Original = s, Count = ParseToInt(s.ViewCount)})
                          .OrderByDescending(a => a.Count)
                          .Take(3);
```

...where `ParseToInt` is a simple parse of that string into just count (just split on ' ' and take first parse into int I guess)

hope this helps some

**EDIT:** this would work for a none - Db scenario

In case of Db bound query - you'd need to parse the 'string' into int using some SQL function that is mapped (and can be mapped to SQL from linq) - but I'm not sure right away what would be the best way to do that. Also you'd need to make a select so it gets you all the data out.
In that case, usually keeping some int field in the Db will probably be the best (instead of a string)